# INDEX, MATCH-Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup, repeat

Using Excel formula, I am trying to find values and match value with previous occurrence. The total repeatation of values is fetched from another table using vlookup function. Along with this another condition is added to check if the time difference in match value is in 1 hour limit. If it is less than one hour, value can't be repeated but if it is greater than 1 hour. the value can be repeated.

I used the formula

```
=IFERROR( INDEX(H2:P2, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF(R$1:$R1, H2:P2) <=
  VLOOKUP(H2:P2, Z$2:AH$3778, 8, FALSE)) * (LEN(H2:P2) > 0) * 
  (COUNTIF($c$2:c2, F2) >= 1) * ( (COUNTIFS(n$1:n1, H2:P2, $c$2:c2, c2) = 
  COUNTIFS($R$1:$R$1, H2:P2, $R$1:$R$1, c2)) * (IFERROR(MATCH(H2:P2, n$1:n1, 0), 0) = 0) * 
 (IFERROR(MATCH(1, (ABS(A2 - INDEX(A$1:A1, MATCH(H2:P2, n$1:n1, 0))) <= TIME(1, 0, 0)), 0), 0) = 0) ), 0) ), "")
```

Column N is where the formuls is used, Column h2:p2 is the values checked with total allowed occurences in vlookup table z:ah. Column F is the hour of the datetime.

Table 1

[image]

vlookup table

[image]

In table 1 last column, value d5e should be displaye but it is not. Any help is really appreciated.Thank you!